# Make PHP wait for python script to complete

Tags: php, python

I'm using the exec() command in PHP to run a python script that will produce some output. This python script queries a rather large PostgreSQL database, so it does take a second or two to execute. Here is my code:

test.php

```
<?php
$output = exec('/usr/local/bin/python2.7 test.py', $output); 
var_dump($output);
?>
```

test.py

```
import nfldb


db = nfldb.connect()
q = nfldb.Query(db)

q.game(season_year=2012, season_type='Regular')
for pp in q.sort('passing_yds').limit(10).as_aggregate():
    print pp.player, pp.passing_yds
```

All of the code works correctly as verified by running the python script from the command line and putting a test "print 10" in the python script to make sure the php script was working.

I'm pretty sure because it takes a few seconds to execute the script that PHP isn't waiting for the output correctly. I tried the set_time_limit() function but it doesn't actually count time from exec().

Any suggestions?

Comment: tried  $output=passthru('/usr/local/bin/python2.7 test.py');  ?

Comment: Yes, passthru doesn't work either.

Comment: lemme guess, you test the python script with user X , and PHP runs the python script with user Y ( user www-data maybe? ) 
.. best guess, the python script has an (access?) problem with running under the PHP user..
idk though, its just a guess

Comment: Well if I include something like "print 10" in the python script, the PHP script will grab the 10, but nothing else. When I run that script from the command line it definitely outputs 10 first and then the other output after about 2 seconds. This is why I believe it just has to do with PHP not waiting long enough

Comment: hmm.... could u try this script?

import time \n print "test";\ntime.sleep(60*10);\nprint "test done";  #i wonder if theres a way to force stdout flush in python

Comment: Ok it does wait for that script to finish. (had to change it to sleep(10) to verify lol). So what could explain why it doesn't wait for the database query to finish?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`popen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) with `r` mode.:

```
<?php
    $handle = popen('/usr/local/bin/python2.7 test.py', 'r');
    $output = fread($handle, 1024);
    var_dump($output);
    pclose($handle);
?>
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. The php script outputs almost instantly, so I know it isn't fully executing that script.

Comment: @user1874544, What happen if you specify the absolute path of `test.py` ?

Comment: That's not the issue because I know the script is already working. I put "print 10" in the python script and the PHP script did output 10, so I know its not a permissions or file location issue.

Comment: @user1874544, Try `popen('/usr/local/bin/python2.7 test.py 2>&1', 'r');` (to catch stderr)

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the return value of `exec()` to $output, which overwrites the actual output with the numeric return value of the program. Don't do that.